# Get SQL query results in a single row from multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a UPC table with below records

```
SKU         ATTR_NAME       ATTR_VALUE
---------   ---------       ----------
38890630    COLOR           Black
38890630    DISC            Y
38890630    SIZE            8
```

And I want the output as below

```
SKU         COLOR     SIZE
---------   ------    ----
38890630    Black      8
```

I tried with multiple ways but couldn't able to get the desired output. Can some one help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sku,
       max(case when attr_name = 'COLOR' then attr_value end) as color,
       max(case when attr_name = 'DISC' then attr_value end) as disc,
       max(case when attr_name = 'SIZE' then attr_value end) as size
from t
group by sku;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT query :

```
WITH UPC_TABLE AS (
    SELECT 38890630 AS SKU, 'COLOR' AS ATTR_NAME, 'BLACK' AS ATTR_VALUE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 38890630 AS SKU, 'DISC' AS ATTR_NAME, 'Y' AS ATTR_VALUE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT 38890630 AS SKU, 'SIZE' AS ATTR_NAME, '8' AS ATTR_VALUE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM 
     UPC_TABLE PIVOT (MAX(ATTR_VALUE) AS ATTR_VALUE FOR (ATTR_NAME) IN (
          'COLOR' AS COLOR
      ,   'DISC' AS DISC
      ,   'SIZE' AS SIZE_FIELD
     )
```

);